# reg.exe add /f not working in batch file, still getting prompted

Tags: batch-file, registry

Simple batch file  Every thing works right except the reg key.

```
@ECHO off

REM Creating Directory if it does not exist

if not exist "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%1\Documents\Favorites\" (mkdir "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%1\Documents\Favorites\"

REM Copy Bookmarks from source to new folder

copy /v "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%1\Favorites\*" "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%1\Documents\Favorites\"

REM Set reg location for favorites

reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Favorites /t REG_SZ /d "%SystemDrive%\home Drive\%1\Documents\Favorites\" /f)
```

But it still prompts to overwrite the reg key, and worse yet, it does it wrong

```
C:\Users\goadmin>MoveFavoritesFolderTest.bat Alex.Wilber

C:\Home drive\Alex.Wilber\Favorites\Best Buy  Official Online Store  Shop Now & Save.url

C:\Home drive\Alex.Wilber\Favorites\Bing.url

C:\Home drive\Alex.Wilber\Favorites\Google.url

C:\Home drive\Alex.Wilber\Favorites\NFLShop - The Official Online Shop of the NFL  2020 NFL Nike Gear, NFL Apparel & NFL Merchandise.url

        4 file(s) copied.

>>> This is the problem
Value Favorites exists, overwrite(Yes/No)? yes
The operation completed successfully.

Even if I say YES the reg key value is set incorrectly. 
"C:\home Drive\Alex.Wilber\Documents\Favorites" /f "
```

What is really strange is this script works fine....

```
@ECHO off

REM Creating Directory if it does not exist
if not exist %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Favorites\ (mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Favorites\

REM Copy Bookmarks from source to new folder
copy /y /v %USERPROFILE%\Favorites\* %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Favorites\

REM Set reg location for favorites
reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Favorites /t REG_SZ /d "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Favorites" /f )
```

Comment: In my continued testing what I seem to have found is it does not like the space in "home Drive"  When I take it out, everything works fine.  

What should I use instead of a space?  %20 doesn't work.

Comment: The backslash before the close quotation mark causes reg.exe to treat the /f as part of the data.

Comment: Try, `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /V Favorites /T Reg_Expand_Sz /D "\"%%SystemDrive%%\home Drive\%~1\Documents\Favorites\"" /F`, instead

Comment: I would also suggest that you change `if not exist "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%1\Documents\Favorites\" (mkdir "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%1\Documents\Favorites\"`, to `If Not Exist "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%~1\Documents\Favorites\" (MD "%SystemDrive%\Home drive\%~1\Documents\Favorites"`. This way, should you have any input argument containing problematic characters, they could be protected by enclosing that argument in doublequotes, without affecting or needing to adjust the code, e.g. `Test.bat "Alex Wilbur"`.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to just switch to PowerShell.  But the client wasn't setup to run PS remotely on all the PCs.  This should do the trick!